# Which SQL Profiler Trace template shows table type parameter values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-profiler

Which profiler trace template can be used to see the table type parameter values that are passed into a stored proc ?

[image: SQL Profiler Templates]

Comment: Sql Server Profiler has been replaced by [Extened Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) which have far lower overhead than the Profiler. Since 2014 all new development goes to Extended Events.

Comment: As for your specific question, are you asking how to capture the *contents* of the table parameters?  The `rpc_completed` event captures parameter values. [This blog post](https://www.scarydba.com/2018/09/24/extended-events-and-stored-procedure-parameter-values/) describes how to capture this using Extended Events. I'm not sure if it captures table parameters too. I think `TSQL_SPs` contains `RCP:Completed` as well

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos. I'll look into these.